# How to set a fixed background with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I've set a fixed background on my website but it's not quite staying fixed when zooming in and out.

This is the site I want to replicate the background from:

http://triangl.com/

Zooming in and out keeps the background completely fixed.

Please see mine:

http://zoeyplayground-com.zoeysite.com/

Zooming in and out will behave differently.

My code is below. This will only set the background on the home page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  if (top.location.pathname === '/')
  {
     jQuery("body").addClass("bodybackground");
  }

});
```

```css
.bodybackground { 
    background: url('/media/import/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Could anybody inform me on what could be causing this? Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `background-size: cover;`

```
.bodybackground { 
    background: url('/media/import/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. I didn't realise it was that simple! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;` as per your necessity. That should fix it.

Comment: This was just answered before, but still appreciated - thank you :)

Comment: @matt136 sorry, didn't check that.